# why can't i use winforms in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

as above, i already added references to system.windows.forms  and WindowsFormsintegration. what i want to do is use richTextBox1.Text
Look at prsc: [image]

Answer (score 4):

Adding a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` doesn't change the fact that you're using the `RichTextBox` from WPF, which doesn't have a `Text` property. The WPF `RichTextBox` hosts a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx), not RTF content like the WinForms `RichTextBox`. Read the MSDN documentation for information on how to work with a `FlowDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use WPF's RichTextBox control?

[image]

Comment: He *is* using the WPF RichTextBox... and he's not finding the Text property on it, since it doesn't exist